python вывод информации в json
Использую python, вывожу словарь в json. Делаю это так:
print(json.dumps(result_reg, indent=4))

Сам словарь выглядит вот так:
{'index': 161, 'name': 'task_31', 'type': 1, 'byte_address': 2658, 'flags': 3, 'description': 'task<>', 'group': 16384, 'value': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 
32, 32, 32]}

А во время вывода словарь выглядит вот так:
{
    "p_default": "NONE",
    "p_value": "NONE",
    "saved_address": "NONE",
    "description": "task<>",
    "name": "task_31",
    "type": 1,
    "ind": "NONE",
    "guid": "NONE",
    "size": "NONE",
    "property": "NONE",
    "group": 16384,
    "p_iec": "NONE",
    "mdb_addr": 61329.0,
    "index": 161,
    "byte_address": 2658,
    "flags": 3,
    "value": [
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32,
        32
    ]
}

Хотелось бы чтобы словарь выводился правильно (чтобы список не выводился построчно каждый символ) можно ли это как то сделать?
В результате хочу получить вот так:
{
    "p_default": "NONE",
    "p_value": "NONE",
    "saved_address": "NONE",
    "description": "task<>",
    "name": "task_31",
    "type": 1,
    "ind": "NONE",
    "guid": "NONE",
    "size": "NONE",
    "property": "NONE",
    "group": 16384,
    "p_iec": "NONE",
    "mdb_addr": 61329.0,
    "index": 161,
    "byte_address": 2658,
    "flags": 3,
    "value": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32 ]
}


Просто уберите indent=4, вы же сами этим параметром указываете, что выводиться должно с отступами, а не одной строкой. Но в целом и тот и другой вариант правильный.

а как тогда выводить словарь с отступами?

Чтобы с отступами - добавляете параметр indent. Если одной строкой - то без него. Вы же сами пишите, что "правильно" - одной строкой, определитесь, как вам нужно.

В целом - укажите, как именно вам нужно. Потому что я предполагаю, что вам не нравится что список value по одному элементу на строку, но это не точно, вы прямо про это нигде не пишете.

да, поправил вопрос

Через json или другие подобные библиотеки - скорее всего никак. Разве что вручную поэлементно собирать строку нужного вида под конкретно ваш словарь.

Начнём сначала. Зачем вам это нужно? JSON - это формат передачи данных. Данные одинаково успешно передаются с любыми отступами и переводами строк корректно если записать . Вывод на экран или куда там - это другой вообще вопрос.

Да, вам нужен именно json на выходе, или удобный просмотр словаря?

мне нужен файл для удобного чтения

Файл - именно json? Или словарь (например, допустимы одинарные кавычки)?

Чтобы элементы списка не выводились по одному, проще всего вручную перевести результат этого значения в строковый тип:
result_reg['value'] = str(result_reg['value'])

И потом вывести также
print(json.dumps(result_reg, indent=4))

Также есть специальные библиотеки для красивого вывода json, например как в этом ответе.
Ещё можно сделать свою функцию сериализации для json.dumps, которая может обрабатывать каждый элемент словаря и аналогично переводить каждый список в словаре в удобный тип. Подробнее есть в документации . Почему работает способ с переводом в строку, объясняется в заметках в этой части документации.

Вывод будет "value": "[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]" а не "value": [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32]. При десериализации вложенный список еще придется дополнительно парсить.
